# laravel route by passing parameter got page not found

Tags: laravel, routes

I just regular do the route with passing parameter

```
Route::get('cabinet', 'CabinetController@index');
Route::get('cabinet/{$id}', 'CabinetController@show');
```

and the controller just simple like this

```
class CabinetController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $cabinets = Cabinet::all();
        return view('detail', compact('cabinets'));
    }
    function show($id)
    {
        $single = Cabinet::find($id);
        $cabinets = Cabinet::all();
        return view('detail', compact('cabinets', 'single'));
    }
}
```

public/cabinet/1
How come i got
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Thank you for solve this for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$` from route declaration:

```
Route::get('cabinet/{id}', 'CabinetController@show');
```